# How to determine DC input voltage of a device without its charger?

Tags: dc, voltage-measurement, charging, light

Had a MotoMaster (Canadian Tire) 27/3 LED flashlight for 4 years now.  Model was discontinued 2-3 years ago.  Lost the charger at least 2 years ago and the light's battery FINALLY died today (!!)

I need to find out what is the correct voltage and order a DC charger for it.  Is there a way to determine the values without the charger?

Obviously, I'm asking because absolutely no value is written on the flashlight, except for polarity and a model # that gives absolutely nothing on Google: 037-9405-8

Comment: I'd say, connect a DC source with ammeter, and ramp up the volts until you see some current start to flow.  That's at least a hint at the lower limit.

Comment: I unfortunately do not have access to a variable DC source.  I only have a multimeter with 2, 20, 200 settings, not a tool with a potentiometer.

Comment: Can you open it up and examine the batteries?

Comment: ... and the charging circuit.

Comment: I think I'll try and crack the case open, yes.  Because my next question if I were to borrow a variable DC source to try rdtsc's suggestion is that say I find that it trickles DC input at 5V, then if I leave it on this minimum input voltage overnight, but unknowingly if the batteries are say 9V, then will it stop charging when the batteries trickle their way up to 5V, meaning I'll think it's fully charged, when it's only half way charged?

Comment: The case doesn't open, I removed every plastic plate that could be pried to no avail.  It's kind of sealed shut in 1 piece.  China garbage.  I wanted to make the most use out of it and do my part in saving the planet, but if the retailer cannot help identifying this and that nobody is selling any, I'll just take a guess that it's 12V and try it.  If it fries then FTS.

Comment: Putting 12 volts across a lithium battery isn't going to do much for saving the planet (or possibly your lungs). Take it to a place that can recycle it and don't throw it in the garbage like you said under Olin's answer.

Comment: @Andy aka : This must be some kind of electronics guy joke I suppose. I was referring to product overconsumption.  Not sure if you were just kidding or if you were serious.  Either way, thanks for actually trying to answer the question, that's very much appreciated.

Comment: Saving the planet doesn’t just involve using less lectricity. No, not a joke and don’t spit your gum on the street. Every bit helps.

Comment: @Andy aka Wow, I'm so confused now.  Did you understand I was referring to avoid purchasing a new plastic/electronic device when I invoked saving the planet or did you legitimately thought I was talking about using less power? Your comments throw me off!

Comment: Do you have access to a variable DC source and some resistors?

Comment: Thanks for replying, but as I said at the top of the comments, I do not have access to a variable DC source unfortunately.  Thanks for trying to help.  I have access to a multimeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really no direct way to know.  You can maybe guess by looking at current draw as a function of voltage, the battery arrangement, etc.

This is really not a electronics problem.  The obvious first approach is to ask the manufacturer.  2 years isn't that long.  Somebody should still know what the charger specs were.

Failing that, search around to find someone else with this device.  This could be someone trying to sell one, for example.  Maybe they will look at their charger and tell you it's voltage as a favor.

Comment: @that-ben Sigh. I hope you don't literally mean "garbage". If it was a rechargeable battery then there is a good chance that it contained hazardous materials. Rechargeable batteries should be treated as hazardous waste and disposed of appropriately.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson Sigh.  Thanks for trying to answer the question.  Also, hope you didn't truely believe I was going to throw this in the "garbage".  It's illegal where I live, so just in case you REALLY thought I was going to literally do that, here's something to help you sleep tonight: I was referring to putting it together with all my other defective electronic material and taking it to the recycle center next year.

Comment: @that-ben For what it's worth, I did leave a comment for your original question that I thought might be helpful. And it's hard to tell when someone is being literal or not so I took you at your word. I'm glad to hear that you are recycling your electronics, wherever you live.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson No problem, but I'm still very let down by the fact it's not possible to make use of my device, since it's all 1 piece of plastic and can't be opened and the input voltage cannot be "guessed" by any other means.  China crap.